# Controller is never executed

Tags: django, angularjs

Assume I have this template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load facebook %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Autos Queridos | Mu&eacute;stranos cu&aacute;nto sabes</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/angular.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/angular-ui-router.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/index.js' %}"></script>
        {% facebook_init %}
            _FacebookSrv.initialize();
        {% endfacebook %}
        <script type="text/javascript">
            AutosQueridos.constant('AutosQueridos.StaticUrl', '{{ STATIC_URL }}');
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['AutosQueridos']);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="AutosQueridos.Base">
        {% verbatim angular %}
        <div ui-view>
            <!-- aca es donde va toda la aplicacion -->
        </div>
        {% endverbatim angular %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Let's analyze it:

1. `angular.bootstrap` is manually called since I need to configure the `STATIC_URL` beforehand as a service. Such constant service is defined before the call.
2. `_FacebookSrv.initialize();` is a custom call which I will describe later. It is executed in the context of `window.fbAsync` (it does not directly interact with the normal flow of an Angular object, nor any scope, nor DOM).
3. `body` has a Controller we'll discuss later (it is the focus of the problem).
4. an internal div has `ui-view` directive in it, since I'm using [ui.router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) as state handler library.

Let's describe stuff which should not be paid attention in this context:

1. The `{% load xxx %}` tags generate no input at all.
2. The `{% verbatim xxx %}`/`{% endverbatim xxx %}` generate no input at all, but are framework-specific tags.
3. The purpose of the `{% static xxx %}` tags is to locate the actual file paths.

So, there's nothing to worry about the tags - they're Django-specific and behave as expected.

The `css/index.css` file has nothing yet. The angular code is located at `js/index.js`:

```
AutosQueridos = angular.module('AutosQueridos', ['ui.router']);

var _FacebookSrv = {
    /* ... */
    initialize: function() {
        /* ... */
    },
    /* ... */
};

/* contents of _FacebookSrv are trimmed to narrow the problem. it is used by AutosQueridosFB and the initialize() has not met the conditions to do anything useful yet, with the code I wrote in my template */

var AutosQueridosFB = function($scope) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
};

/* methods of AutosQueridosFB were trimmed to narrow the problem. this factory is not yet used*/

AutosQueridos_Facebook = AutosQueridos.factory('AutosQueridos.Facebook', ['$scope', function($scope){ return new AutosQueridosFB($scope); }]);

AutosQueridos_Base = AutosQueridos.controller('AutosQueridos.Base', ['$state', '$rootScope', function($state, $rootScope){
    /* pay attention to THIS controller */
    console.log('nestor');
    $state.go('welcome');
}]);

AutosQueridos_Welcome = AutosQueridos.controller('AutosQueridos.Welcome', ['$scope', '$state', '$rootScope', function($scope, $state, $rootScope){
    /* there's nothing yet in these controllers */
}]);

AutosQueridos_Roulette = AutosQueridos.controller('AutosQueridos.Roulette', ['$scope', '$state', '$rootScope', '$http', function($scope, $state, $rootScope, $http){
    /* there's nothing yet in these controllers */
}]);

AutosQueridos_Trivia = AutosQueridos.controller('AutosQueridos.Trivia', ['$scope', '$state', '$rootScope', '$http', function($scope, $state, $rootScope, $http){
    /* there's nothing yet in these controllers */
}]);

AutosQueridos.config(['$stateProvider', 'AutosQueridos.StaticUrl', function($sp, url) {
    //
    // Now set up the states
    $sp
        .state('welcome', {
            templateUrl: url + "partials/welcome.html",
            controller: 'AutosQueridos.Welcome'
        })
        .state('roulette', {
            templateUrl: url + 'partials/roulette.html',
            controller: 'AutosQueridos.Roulette'
        })
        .state('trivia', {
            templateUrl: url + 'partials/trivia.html',
            controller: 'AutosQueridos.Trivia'
        })
}]);
```

**My issue is here**: the `AutosQueridos.Base` controller in the `body` is never executed: I don't see 'nestor' being shown in the console, nor the "welcome" state being reflected (state templates have dumb content, like "Welcome!"). **What am I missing**?

**Updated**: I don't get any 4xx/5xx error - files are loaded as expected. I don't either get a javascript error in console.

Comment: Are you sure your scripts are loaded and no 404s are there? just put some logs before the controller registrations to see if the scripts are being loaded properly

Comment: I checked right now, as you told, and no file gives error. Dependencies are resolved (i.e. ui.router module is loaded, and index.js is loaded with my custom application). Get no console error, nor http error.

Comment: Wrap your bootstrap inside `angular.element(document).ready(function() { angular.bootstrap(document, ['AutosQueridos']);});` and try

Comment: You're great! You deserve a prize I cannot tell here because it's an all-ages site ;). For now, put it as the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: great!! sure i'l add it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start bootstrap only when all the modules have been loaded and document is ready. So wrap your function inside document ready like this:-

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['AutosQueridos']);
});
```

This is the sequence that your code should follow:

- After the page and all of the code is loaded, find the root element of your AngularJS application, which is typically the root of the document.
- Call angular.bootstrap to compile the element into an executable, bi-directionally bound application.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli Glad i could.. :)